# How to recharge an ENTER event in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have an SPA developed with AngularJS and Bootstrap. The user can enter a username and password to log into the application. I wanted to allow that, after entering the username and value, pressing the ENTER key would trigger the login process as if the `Login` button was clicked.

The code I'm using is:

```
    Charge_Enter_Event_for_Login = function () {
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#Username').keypress(function(e){
                if(e.keyCode==13) {
                    $('#Do_Login').click();
                    return false;
                }
            });

            $('#Password').keypress(function(e){
                if(e.keyCode==13) {
                    $('#Do_Login').click();
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
    }

    Charge_Enter_Event_for_Login() ;
```

(The element `Do_Login` is the button that can be clicked).

This works OK the first time. However, if I logout then the event is no longer  being triggered, unless I use the browser's reload button.

I also tried to call the function `Charge_Enter_Event_for_Login()` within the logout function, but with no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `#Do_Login` button is an `<input type="submit">` tag, then it will be triggered automatically when ENTER is pressed while focus is on a `<input type="text">` or `<input type="password">` element.

To answer the question, my guess would be: when login is successful, you are probably hiding the login form somehow? Probably by destroying the `form` DOM object. When the `form` is later recreated to show the login form again after logout, you would need to attach the events again, because its a new DOM object.

Comment: Thanks @C14L. I think that the second paragraph describes the situation. The problem is that the HTML within which the Username and Password inputs are presented, contains a number of `ng-if` that condition the display of elements. The other problem is that, upon logout, there is no a `refresh` but just a presentation of the landing page. A refresh would solve the problem too (I think).

Comment: Using `ng-if`destroys and re-creates the DOM element. Use `ng-show` instead, that will only hide the element, and the attached events will still function when the element is visible again.

Comment: Well, it took me more time that expected, but I finally got to check your suggestion of sing `ng-show`. I work exactly as you explained. Thanks @C14L.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use *angularjs* directive `ng-submit` with `form` element. Your code looks very raw. Please go through the angular site first and understand how angular directives work. Also, if you have angularjs you don't need to use *jQuery* as you can use the *two-way* binding provided by angular. I have created a jsbin for your scenario [here](https://jsbin.com/zovecug/edit?html,js,console,output). Please use it and also try using `angularjs` directives as much as you can

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your event is bind only on pageload. You should really not use jquery for this kind of thing.

You have 2 possible solutions :

- use a directive on your input :

  ```
   angular.module('yourAppName')
      .directive('submitAction', function () {
          return function (scope, element, attrs) {
              element.on("keypress", function (e) {
                  e.preventDefault();

                  if(e.keyCode === 13) {
                      scope.$apply(function () {
                          scope.$eval(attrs.submitAction);
                      });
                  }
              });
          };
      });
  ```

so your input look like this :

`<input type="text" id="Username" submit-action="functionToExecute()">`

- or use the angular `ng-keypress` directive :

`<input type="text" id="Username" ng-keypress="functionToExecute($event)">`

with this solution, you need to check the value of the keyCode in the function.

Comment: Thanks @Lithium. Will check the second option (later on) and let you know. One question though: You are defining a directive `submitAction` while using `submit-action` (i.e. missing the in-between "`-`" character in the directive declaration). I'd seen this a number of times and never stopped to check why. Is this the way Angular wants s to use it?

Comment: Yeah, this is how we should declare directives, `myDirective` with camel case, but when we use it in an element on html, it become `my-directive`.